# Disable autosuggestion/autocomplete on editText without using Visible Password method

Tags: android, autocomplete, android-edittext

I'm trying to disable auto-complete on my editText and I've tried the following methods:

```
android:inputType="textFilter" //doesn't work
```

or

```
android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"   // doesn't work
```

or

```
myedittext.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS); // doesn't work
```

or

```
myedittext.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD); // doesn't work
```

or

```
android:inputType="textVisiblePassword" //it does work, but I can't toggle kanji
//if I use Japanese characters, so I'd like another method please...
```

Since the editText is supposed to work for both english and japanese alphabets/characters, the last method doesn't really cut it out for me because I can't toggle the Japanese characters (they have like three alphabet systems so there is a need to toggle...)

Is there a method that would work please? Thank you.