# How do I set threshold to my EditText?

Tags: android, threshold

Let's say when the user starts typing into the `EditText`, the autocomplete doesn't appear until the user has typed say maybe 20 characters?

I've tried placing the following code into the layout XML file but it didn't work:

```
android:completionThreshold="20"
```

I've also tried this following one in the Java class but it didn't work either:

```
myedittext.setThreshold(20);
// it says 'The method setThreshold(int) is undefined for the type EditText'
```

**Edited:**

It appears that my question might be misunderstood so I would like to clarify:

The user types a word into the editText. You know how auto-complete appears after 1 character or so? I don't want it to appear so soon... My aim is to make it appear only maybe after the user has typed a certain amount of characters... That's pretty much it.

Apologies for the misunderstanding. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using an [`AutoCompleteTextView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html) instead of a regular `EditText`? That might be the issue, since it's the former one that has the [completion threshold](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html#attr_android%3acompletionThreshold).

But, based on your latest updates to the question, input type of the `EditText` on the fly, after the user has typed X number of letters (I have never tried it, though). Something like this:

```
myEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, 
            int before, int count) {}

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, 
            int count, int after) {}

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        String text = myEditText.getText().toString();
        int maxChar = 5;

        // Suggest words if the word is long enough,
        // or prevent suggestions if not log enough
        int type = text.length() > maxChar ? 
                TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_AUTO_CORRECT : 
                TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS;

        myEditText.setInputType(type);
    }
});
```

Now it's a matter of you trying this out to see if works for you.

Comment: @Fuchsia: Just refer to the first link in the answer.

Comment: I did... I'm still looking, but I don't quite understand >_<

Comment: @Fuchsia, check my first link. It's pretty straightforward to replace an `EdtiText` for an `AutoCompleteTextView` and use its advantages. Just replace it in the layout, and then in the Java code you do something similar to the snippet on my first link.

Comment: Hrm... In the link, I'm to make my own string array right? But if I want to use the dictionary? Let's say it's pretty much the same thing as typing words in messages, it's just that the words show up only after you typed a certain amount of characters...

Comment: @Fuchsia : this is a different question. What you are referring to is, I think, the system's predictive typing. You cannot change its behavior unless you implement your own keyboard.

Comment: It's the same question as I asked... But perhaps people misunderstood >_< I did say editText... That's why I didn't quite get the usage of AutoCompleteTextView...

Comment: You got to provide some more actual info about your use case for us to help further.

Comment: They are guessing words, say for spelling, so when they type in the box, it will check if the word is correct (this part no prob). Unfortunately, the auto-complete comes out, so they already know the correct spelling when they just type like one or so characters. I've asked on how to disable but there was no answer for that here (bcos I'm trying to support both english and japanese): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21914768/disable-autosuggestion-autocomplete-on-edittext-without-using-visible-password-m. So I thought maybe I could increase the threshold instead...